# The difference between the ordination of the 70 elders and that of Joshua?

Tags: rabbis, moshe-rabbeinu, semicha, yehoshua-joshua

In the process of the ordination of the elders, God executed the procedure without Moses' assistance:

> "וַיֹּאמֶר ה' אֶל־מֹשֶׁה אֶסְפָה־לִּי שִׁבְעִים אִישׁ ... וְלָקַחְתָּ אֹתָם אֶל־אֹהֶל מוֹעֵד וְהִתְיַצְּבוּ שָׁם עִמָּךְ׃
> וְיָרַדְתִּי וְדִבַּרְתִּי עִמְּךָ שָׁם **וְאָצַלְתִּי מִן־הָרוּחַ אֲשֶׁר עָלֶיךָ וְשַׂמְתִּי עֲלֵיהֶם** וְנָשְׂאוּ אִתְּךָ בְּמַשָּׂא הָעָם וְלֹא־תִשָּׂא אַתָּה לְבַדֶּךָ׃
> Then the LORD said to Moses, “Gather for Me seventy of Israel’s elders ... and bring them to the Tent of Meeting and let them take their place there with you. I will come down and speak with you there, and **I will draw upon the spirit that is on you and put it upon them**; they shall share the burden of the people with you, and you shall not bear it alone." [Num 11.17](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.11.17?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=he)

However, in the ordination of Joshua God asked Moses to do the Semichah:

> "וַיֹּאמֶר ה' אֶל־מֹשֶׁה קַח־לְךָ אֶת־יְהוֹשֻׁעַ בִּן־נוּן אִישׁ אֲשֶׁר־רוּחַ בּוֹ וְסָמַכְתָּ אֶת־יָדְךָ עָלָיו׃ וְהַעֲמַדְתָּ אֹתוֹ לִפְנֵי אֶלְעָזָר הַכֹּהֵן וְלִפְנֵי כָּל־הָעֵדָה וְצִוִּיתָה אֹתוֹ לְעֵינֵיהֶם׃ **וְנָתַתָּה מֵהוֹדְךָ עָלָיו** לְמַעַן יִשְׁמְעוּ כָּל־עֲדַת בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל׃"
> Have him stand before Eleazar the priest and before the whole community, and commission him in their sight. **And [you] invest him with some of your authority**, so that the whole Israelite community may obey. [Num 27.20](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.27.20?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en)

The additional differences that I can spot:

- that in the first case, God moved Moses' רוח, while in the latter, his הוד.
- that the former took place away from the whole community while the latter was intentionally before it

Why those differences?